# WSO2 API Manager(wso2am-4.0.0) - Recurring JMS Error

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I have setup wso2am-4.0.0 and I have configured readonly ldap as the primary userstore.

After changing to readonly ldap, the following error is seen in the logs and it is recurring forever. The API calls also seem to be failing due to it.

```
- Error creating JMS consumer for Siddhi-JMS-Consumer javax.jms.JMSException: Error registering consumer: org.wso2.andes.AMQChannelClosedException: Error: org.wso2.andes.AMQSecurityException: Permission denied: binding notification [error code 403: access refused] [error code 504: channel error]
at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQSession$6.execute(AMQSession.java:2187)
at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQSession$6.execute(AMQSession.java:2130)
at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.executeRetrySupport(AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.java:339)
at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection$3.run(AMQConnection.java:665)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.executeRetrySupport(AMQConnection.java:662)
at org.wso2.andes.client.failover.FailoverRetrySupport.execute(FailoverRetrySupport.java:102)
at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQSession.createConsumerImpl(AMQSession.java:2195)
at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQSession.createConsumer(AMQSession.java:1100)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.jms.utils.JMSUtils.createConsumer(JMSUtils.java:495)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.jms.JMSTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.createConsumer(JMSTaskManager.java:1010)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.jms.JMSTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.getMessageConsumer(JMSTaskManager.java:865)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.jms.JMSTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.receiveMessage(JMSTaskManager.java:612)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.jms.JMSTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.run(JMSTaskManager.java:533)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.andes.AMQChannelClosedException: Error: org.wso2.andes.AMQSecurityException: Permission denied: binding notification [error code 403: access refused] [error code 504: channel error]
at org.wso2.andes.client.handler.ChannelCloseMethodHandler.methodReceived(ChannelCloseMethodHandler.java:100)
at org.wso2.andes.client.handler.ClientMethodDispatcherImpl.dispatchChannelClose(ClientMethodDispatcherImpl.java:163)
at org.wso2.andes.framing.amqp_0_91.ChannelCloseBodyImpl.execute(ChannelCloseBodyImpl.java:140)
at org.wso2.andes.client.state.AMQStateManager.methodReceived(AMQStateManager.java:111)
```

Any solution for this is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your Primary User store (Read-Only LDAP) have a user that can be used as an Admin user in the API Manager server? Have you configured the API Manager server with the respective Username and Password in the `deployment.toml` (with a user which resides in the LDAP)?

Comment: @Athiththan Yes. A separate user has been created in the ldap and the respective username and password has been configured in the deployment.toml as well.

Comment: If your password has special characters, please do follow the mentioned steps in this [Doc](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/security/logins-and-passwords/maintaining-logins-and-passwords/) to update the required configurations with encoded strings. The mentioned error is produced from the JMS and it is not able to connect to the server due to access denial. This might be due to authentication is not happening properly or the Admin privileges are not set as expected.

Comment: @Athiththan Thanks for the reply. Could you kindly specify on which characters not to be used as the password? Also could you specify which privileges should be granted to the user?

Comment: @Athiththan Also, I configured as per the document referred. Passed the super_admin password inside a CDATA tag and also passed the same encoded password under the apim.throttling.jms configuration. Still the error could be seen.